# Где в october cms писать классы, общие для всего сайта?

Tags: laravel, october, octobercms

Где в october cms архитектурно правильно писать классы, общие для всего сайта?
Понятно, что можно в компонентах или на страницах и других "костыльных местах", которые можно добавлять в соответствующих местах, или в autoload прописать. Но, возможно, для этого отведено определенное место?